# News shot in screenwriting

Tags: formatting, screenwriting

I'm writing a screenplay that incorporates various news shots. I plan to use various news shots as expositions. My story takes place in the future, and I want various news shots that display the top stories that portray the political climate of the fictional world I want to create.

What I'd like to do is set the scene in my opening shot as follows---

NEWS REPORTS 
EXT. THE SUPREME COURT BUILDING - DAY

A young man, TERRELL BROWN is surrounded by the PRESS. A LAWYER, is escorting him up the steps to court to challenge a landmark case in the supreme court.

```
                         NEWS REPORTER(V.O)
                Terrell Brown is being escorted into The Supreme court building .
```

INT. SOUND-ROOM - SAME TIME

A young pundit, AYITA JONES is hosting her own podcast. She's talking to guest, DEVON EVANS about the case.

```
                     AYITA
                What do you think will the outcome of this case?

                    DEVON
               I believe that it could set a new precedent for the country.
```

I want the scenes of news shots to act as intercalery shots to set the stage and act as exposition, in between the dramatic scenes of the script.

**How am I supposed to format a news shot in screenwriting? Am I already on the right track or not?**

Answer (score 1):

I think you want an INSERT.

From https://screenwriting.io/what-is-an-insert/

> An insert is a shot — often a close-up — that focuses on a specific detail. If necessary, these shots can be written into a screenplay, but most inserts will be called for by the director.

```
Patton smiles as he flips slowly through the stack. 

He stops on one in particular.

INSERT – PHOTO

of a 12-year-old Patton and his father in upper deck seats at the 1997 World Series, hot dogs in hand.

            PATTON

Go Marlins.
```

I think if it's a newsroom or other "live" scene, you write it just as it is, with a clear location indicating it, whether "living room/podcast studio" or "generic evening news desk"